# Can a user script modify or apply syntax highlighting in SE sites?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, javascript, code-block

SE currently use Prettify for syntax highlighting. However, there are still some languages which have no support from default Prettify, or by the extensions that SE may be using. If I wanted to test or use an extension to Prettify on SE sites, how can I do so?

---

I tried, manually using the developer console, to append a `<script>` tag containing Prettify extension. That worked when I tried it on a post which used syntax highlighting. On a post which didn't have any syntax-highlighted parts, I get this error:

```
vim.js?_=1461171970788:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: PR is not defined
```

Now, how do I apply the new extension to a code block on that page? Manually changing the `pre` tag's `class` attribute doesn't seem to make an difference.

---

Turns out, that was because I forgot to append `lang-` to the language name. This finally worked:

```
StackExchange.using('prettify', function () {a = document.createElement('script'); a.src="//…/foo.js"; $('head').append(a);})
```

And then `<!-- language: foo -->` markers started working.

Comment: Not sure what you're actually trying but the full un-minified script used by SE is [here](https://dev.sstatic.net/Js/prettify-full.js?v=7a102effc5f0). Maybe you can figure out if there is something changed or hidden that you expect to be available.

Comment: @rene turns out that question had nothing highlighted and so the script wasn't loaded at all. I tried on another post, and the script loaded fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make sure Prettify is loaded by invoking `StackExchange.using('prettify', <callback>)` in your script, which will then guarantee that `PR` is available in the global scope.

I did this a while ago as part of a quick [proof-of-concept for Mathematica highlighting](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/blob/master/stack-utilities-mathematica-prettify.user.js) (which may or may not work correctly now, depending on whether or not anything's changed).