# Where is the StackExchange JavaScript object documented?

Tags: support, javascript

I learnt of the StackExchange JavaScript object recently via [Tim Stone's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278614/270345). Is this is the same object documented in [the API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib)? That doesn't mention the `using()` function from Tim Stone's answer.

Where do I find more about functions like `StackExchange.using()`?

Comment: This isn't a public/supported API. It's just our object structure for the page. It could change at any point in time.

Comment: @NickCraver :( And I suppose if you did document it, [people would beat on you if it changed](https://xkcd.com/1172/). Can you leave a message in chat or somewhere transient about what I can do with it currently? I'm looking to set the default syntax highlighting language for a page.

Comment: You can't do anything like that currently. At least, not in any way useful though that object. We're just using Prettify, so you're just in the DOM looking for lang-* classes, replacing them and calling `prettyPrint();` again...

Comment: @Meta with the usual time frame of 6-8 "weeks" for SE to do things, I don't mind a few hours down the drain so I can enjoy syntax highlighting for weeks. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) already [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278631/where-is-the-stackexchange-javascript-object-documented/278632#comment902368_278631) the API for the client-side JavaScript object `StackExchange` isn't public.

You can however rather easily obtain a non-minified version of that file from the [Developer CDN](https://dev.sstatic.net).

The object is created in the [full.js](https://dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.js?v=7a102effc5f0) and that version is annotated with comments in some spots.

You'll find this as a start:

```
// Begin c:\teamcity\buildagent\work\6daa56c20f8558cf\stackoverflow\content\js\realtime-se.js

var StackExchange = StackExchange || {};

StackExchange.realtime = (function () {
```